# HIghcharts with chart and data at the same time

Tags: highcharts

I am new to highcharts and trying to show the chart and data at the same time.

Like the whole display should be like this.

First column : Station Name(data)
Second column : horizontal bar
Third column : Data.

Is it possible to paint it only using highcharts API's ?

Thanks
Sukanta

Comment: Could you show mockup? But in general, Highcharts is designed to display data in a chart.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically talking about a regular bar chart with a categorical axis and data labels:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/288/

```
categories:['group a','group b','group c','group d','group e']
```

I don't think that there is a default setting that will align the data labels all to the right in a column as you requested, but I am sure there is a workaround that will allow it to be done.